# convert type automatically, when signature of non-static function is so obvious

Tags: c++, c++11

I am seeking a C++ feature that work as followed:-

Within a certain scope, using a custom converter function, C++ can automatically ***convert*** all class instances (int, in this example) to another class (Person), in all places that the name and signature of function is obvious.

**Example**

I have a function for registering a cash account to a person.

```
void Person::addAccount(Account account){...}
//..... There are a lot of other functions of Person.
//..... This is why I want converting to be automatic.
```

The person has "id".   I can query Person object from "id"

```
Person* PersonManager::getPerson(int id){ .... }
//id is the main "communicator" that all systems use
```

Therefore, I can add an account to a person id like this :-

```
personManager()->getPerson(5)->addAccount(Account());
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.  :-

```
class X{
    Person* super_smart_converter$$$(int id){    
        return  personManager()->getPerson(id);
    }

    void f(){
        int id=5;
        id->addAccount(Account()); //<-- I am captivated by how short it can be.
        //^ call super_smart_converter$$$ automatically 
        //   because addAccount is a unique name belongs to Person only
    }
}
```

Do C++ has such feature, or something similar?
or... are there any coding techniques to achieve the similar result?

**Note:** I can't overload operator -> of ID (if it happen to be a class) because the id is used in many unrelated places, and can be converted into many unrelated types.

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};

// Overloads to retrieve wanted object from id
Person& Convert(tag<Person>, int id) { return  personManager()->getPerson(id); }

// The magic function
template <typename T, typename C, typename M, typename ... Ts>
decltype(auto) super_smart_caller(T&& id, M (C::*m), Ts&&...args)
{
    auto& c = Convert(tag<C>{}, std::forward<T>(id));
    return (c.*m)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

And call may look like

```
super_smart_caller(1, &Person::print, 42);
super_smart_caller("John", &Person::print, 0);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/JnkDPy)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about your question.
I think you can use construct function like

```
class Person
{
    ...
    Person(Account account)
    {
        ....
        addAccount(account);
        ....
    }

};
```

then you can just add a object person by one line .

you can add function in class X also

```
class X{
    void add_account_by_id(int id, const Account& account)
    {
        personManager()->getPerson(id)->addAccount(account);
    }

    void f(){
        int id=5;

        Account account=Account();
        ...
        add_account_by_id(id, account);


        //id->addAccount(account); //<-- I am captivated by how short it can be
        //^ call super_smart_caster$$$ automatically 
        //   because addAccount is a unique name belongs to Person only
    }
};
```

If you want to call all the function in Person ,you can implement by template like this:

```
class Person
{
public:
    int AddAccount(int i)
    {
        printf("test");
    }
};
class X
{
    template<typename TFunc,typename TParam>
    void CallPersonFunc(int id , TFunc func, const TParam& param)
    {
        Person person = GetPersonById(id);
        (person.*func)(param);
    }

    Person GetPersonById(int id)
    {
        //...
        return Person();
    }
public:
    void func()
    {
        CallPersonFunc(5,&Person::AddAccount,1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, you understand the question.  Your provided solution is that I must encapsulate every function of Person. :(  .... Thank, though.

Comment: Better, but I still have to explicitly declare that "5" is a person e.g. by 1) CallPersonFunc    2) "&Person" ... this 2) can't be avoided ...  Thank again :)